# Is there are name for this type of ambiguity?

Tags: ambiguity

Is there a name for the ambiguity that arises when you can't tell a word's part of speech due to capitalization ? E.g.

Run Engine

Ambiguity: Command or compound noun?

Comment: Would it be less ambiguous if it were written "Run engine" or "RUN ENGINE"?

Comment: Why capitalization? Is this any different from the ambiguity in "Fruit flies like a banana"?